# Search Functionality based on record information

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger

I have two objects "Apartment__c" and "Opportunity_potentials__c", Based on information like Bedroom(1bhk,2bhk..) and Location given in apartment, i'm searching available opportunity, in Opportunity_potentials__c record both Bedroom  and Location are multi-select picklist(even in apartment bedroom and location are multi-select picklist). So now the problem is when i select  multiple location and bedroom in opportunity that particular record won't get displayed in search results. I will get correct result when i have opportunity with single value in bedroom  and location.

here is my Controller

```
public with sharing class Apartment_to_opp_search {

    // Instance fields
        public String searchTerm {get; set;}
        public String bedroom {get; set;}
        public string size { get; set; }
        public string BudgetMin { get; set; }


        Set<id> ids=new Set<Id>();
        public String Locaton { get; set; }
        public String propertytype { get; set; }
        public String leadtype { get; set; }
        public String preference{ get; set; }
        public String qp { get; set; }
        public List<categoryWrapper2> searchResults {get;set;}

        List<Location__c> locations=new List<Location__c>();  
        List<project__c> projects=new List<Project__c>();  

        public Apartment_to_opp_search(ApexPages.StandardController controller) 
        {
            this.qp = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
            bedroom=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('bedroom__c');
            Locaton =ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('location');
            system.debug(Locaton);
            preference=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('preference');
            propertytype=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('property type');
            system.debug(propertytype);
            leadtype=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('lead type');
            size=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('sqfeet');
            BudgetMin=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('MinBudget'); 
            system.debug(BudgetMin);

         }

         public List<categoryWrapper2> selectedCategories 
         {
             get {
              if (selectedCategories == null)selectedCategories = new List<categoryWrapper2>();
                return selectedCategories;
               }
               set;
              }   

         public PageReference back() 
         {
                selectedCategories.clear();
                ids.clear();
                return page.opportunity_search_page;
            }
          // fired when the search button is clicked

          public PageReference search() 
          {
               if (searchResults == null) {
                searchResults = new List<categoryWrapper2>(); // init the list if it is null
                  } else {
                searchResults.clear(); // clear out the current results if they exist
            }

        string vacant1 ='Prospecting';
        string vacant2 ='';

      String qry='Select Name,Id,Account__r.name,Bedroom__c,Location__c,Maximum_Square_Feet__c,Minimum_Square_Feet__c,Lead_Type__c,Maximum_Budget__c,Minimum_Budget__c,Property_Type__c,Opportunity_Stage__c From Opportunity_Potential__c where  Opportunity_Stage__c=:vacant1 ';
       system.debug(qry);

        string[] bedroom1=bedroom.split(';');
        system.debug(bedroom1);
        string[] location=Locaton.split(';');
        string[] propertytypes=propertytype.split(';');


        if (bedroom!='')
             qry+=' and Bedroom__c in :bedroom1';
             system.debug(qry);
      if(Locaton!='')

       qry+=' and Location__c in :location'; 

            if(propertytype!='')
            qry+=' and  Property_Type__c in :propertytypes';
            string buy1= '%' +'Sale' + '%';
              string rent1='%' +'Rent' + '%';
            if(leadtype=='For Sale')
               qry+=' and Lead_Type__c LIKE :buy1';
             if(leadtype=='For Rent')
              qry+=' and Lead_Type__c like:rent1';

           system.debug(qry);
           for(Opportunity_Potential__c c : Database.query(qry)) {
            // create a new wrapper by passing it the category in the constructor
            CategoryWrapper2 cw = new CategoryWrapper2(c);
            // add the wrapper to the results
            searchResults.add(cw);
                    } 
               system.debug(searchResults);                  
        return null;

    } 
      public PageReference next() {

        // clear out the currently selected categories
       ids.clear();
 System.debug('****************'+selectedCategories);
 System.debug('###################'+searchResults);
        // add the selected categories to a new List

        for (CategoryWrapper2 cw : searchResults) {
            if (cw.checked==true)
                selectedCategories.add(new CategoryWrapper2(cw.cat));
        //  ids.add(cw.cat.id);
            }
      for (CategoryWrapper2 cw : selectedCategories) {
          ids.add(cw.cat.id);
            }
        // ensure they selected at least one category or show an error message.
        if (selectedCategories.size() > 0) {
                    System.Debug('///////////////////////////'+selectedCategories);
         return Page.Category_Results1;
    //  return Page.pdftomail;
        } else {
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Please select at least one Category.'));
            return null;
        }       
     }  
}
```

and here is my wrapper class categorywrapper2

```
public class CategoryWrapper2 {

    public Boolean checked{ get; set; }
    public Opportunity_Potential__c cat { get; set;}

    public CategoryWrapper2(){
        cat = new Opportunity_Potential__c ();
        checked = false;
    }

    public CategoryWrapper2(Opportunity_Potential__c c){
        cat = c;
        checked = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you try using // in the split method to split the values correctly. sometimes it would be a special character issue which may result in query failure. Locaton.split('//;');

Comment: Can you add an example of an input that doesn't work, and the result of the `system.debug(qry)` statement for that input?